# Eclipse adding project reference

Tags: android, eclipse, reference, project

Could someone please explain the difference between adding a project reference by Properties > Android > Add project reference

And

Properties > Java Build Path > Projects tab > Add project reference.

Are these two methods doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    By Properties > Android > Add project reference
```

- You can only add libraries project as a references.

  ```
  Using the other method:  
  By Properties > Java Build Path > Projects tab > Add project reference.
  ```
- You can also add whatever kind of project as a reference. Doesn't matter if it is library project, android, java, C++ or whatever kind project that is in the same workspace of your project.

If you want to add .jar files I recommend you to use the  By Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add JARS or Add External JARS.

Also you can copy and paste the .jar file inside of your libs folder in your project. But you have to copy/paste in Eclipse, because in this way, eclipse update the references automatically into your project (in this way, the project know that you added a new library)

Answer (score 0):

```
By Properties > Android > Add project reference
```

you can add only source code  library

and

```
By Properties > Java Build Path > Projects tab > Add project reference.
```

you can add source code library , external jar and jar like **android-support-v4.jar**